# Spring batch and transactions

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-transactions

My question relates to Spring batch and transactions

How we can restrict the Transactions in the Spring Batch and how to restrict/control the Items reading from Database? Please help in this.

Actually i have to read database table rows and with that need to call webservice and once getting the response from web-service, need to feed in the Database. This is the entire flow i want to achieve. For that i need to read the items from DB in chunks and call the web-service.

I know that the writing can be controlled by commit-interval. But i need to control the items reading from DB.

Comment: What do you mean by restric reading ?

Comment: i want to control the items reading. Also please provide a link also if you find to support such thing...

Comment: Actually i have to read database table rows and with that need to call webservice and once getting the response from web-service, need to feed in the Database. This is the entire flow i want to achieve. For that i need to read the items from DB in chunks and call the web-service. Any help??

Comment: I don't think Spring batch supports it by it self, you can write your own reader which will read say 20 records and return on object having all data and then you can pass same to writer. Otherwise , these is no direct way in spring batch.

Comment: You can explain scneario in more detail in question , like you explained in comment and then tag question with batch processing  and J2EE . Someone might give some better approach. Spring batch is not solution for same.

Comment: done. hope to get an easy way of doing it.

Comment: What are you doing with the web service?  You could use an `ItemWriter` to call it if it's persisting data of some kind.  The `ItemWriter#write` method takes the list of items within the chunk.